# How to enable Tasks Toolbar in Informatica Manager

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

How can I enable my Tasks toolbar in Informatica Manager? Thank you in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The workflow must be checked out first in order for the Tasks toolbar to be enabled. Just figured it out.